# Orchard - saving feedback form record to a database

Tags: orchardcms

I am pretty new to Orchard. I created a simple feedback form widget. This is what I have in the controller to insert the data into the database, but it's not working.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackViewModel form)
    {
        var feedback = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New<FeedbackPart>("FeedbackWidget");

        feedback.EmailAddress = form.EmailAddress;
        feedback.Name = form.Name;
        feedback.Comment = form.Comment;
        feedback.SubmitDate = DateTime.Now;

        _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(feedback);

        return View("FeedbackSent", form);
    }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? It doesn't throw any errors, but I don't see any new record being inserted to the database table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice here is probably to check this out, which will be part of Orchard 1.5m but already works on 1.4: http://orchardcustomforms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var feedback = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New<FeedbackPart>("FeedbackWidget");
```

Assuming `FeedbackWidget` is the content type which represents the widget you are using to collect the feedback, I'm not sure if you want to be creating a new *widget* every time.

It would make more sense to have a second content type - `FeedbackResponse` with a part to hold `EmailAddress`, `Name`, `Comment` etc, and create a new `FeedbackResponse` content item on which to store the individual bits of feedback.

Comment: I just noticed, I see 15+ Feedback content items in the admin dashboard, one for each feedback I submitted. This is not desirable, as when the site goes live, the list will grow very big. I guess creating a feedback page as a content type is not the right way to do it.